# Making dynamic dictionary in js with unique header values and data inside it

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, list, dictionary

My JSON data is like :

```
 "data": [
        {           
            "docName": "hpc",
            "station": "delhi"
        },
        {            
            "docName": "Dr. Sharma",
            "station": "chd"
        },
        {           
            "docName": "ansh",
            "station": "chandigrag"
        },
        {          
            "docName": "Bhupi",
            "station": "jhujhar nagar"
        },
        {            
            "docName": "varun",
            "station": "punjab"
        },
        {           
            "docName": "varun",
            "station": "delhi"
        },
        {           
            "docName": "Rk",
            "station": "delhi"
        },
        {
            "docName": "Rk",
            "station": "delhi"
        }  
    ]
```

This has multiple stations and unique doctor name and i want to make listing as

```
data: {
delhi: {
0 : hpc,
1 : varun,
2 : RK,
3 : ansh
},
chandigrah: {
0 : ansh,
1:  ansh,
},
stationName : {
0 : doctorName,
1 : doctorNam
}
}
```

Like this i need unique stations as header and names inside those headers
I am trying to make dictionary ???///

Comment: Maybe you should post an example of the output you expect. It's quite difficult understanding the outcome you desire.

Comment: Can you post the actual code? Some of us can't see Imgur links :(

Comment: try your code in stackblitz or some online ide and share the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is the simple low level programming, we can tweak it better for good result.
Also sharing you [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-9e2kmh?file=index.js)

```js
var button = document.getElementById('testButton');
button.addEventListener('click', test);

var obj = [{ s_no: "1" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc1" ,station: "chennai" },
{ s_no: "2" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc2" ,station: "madurai" },
{ s_no: "3" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc3" ,station: "trichy" },
{ s_no: "4" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc4" ,station: "kovai" },
{ s_no: "5" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc5" ,station: "chennai" },
{ s_no: "6" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc6" ,station: "madurai" },
{ s_no: "7" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc7" ,station: "chennai" },
{ s_no: "8" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc8" ,station: "madurai" },
{ s_no: "9" ,userId: "1" ,name: "RAhul" ,designation: "MD" ,docName: "doc9" ,station: "chennai" }];

function test(){
  var resultObj = {};
  for(var i=0; i< obj.length; i++){
    var station = obj[i].station
    var result = obj.filter(_obj => {
      return _obj.station === station;
    });
     let docArray = result.map(a => a.docName);
     resultObj[station] = docArray;
  }

  console.log(resultObj);
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<button id="testButton">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Uthistran ! this saved my time

Comment: Good that it helped you. :)